# Assinging variable value to a new column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops

I have created 3 new variables a,b and c using certain conditions. Now I want to assign these variables to a new column in a pandas DataFrame again using some conditions.

I want a code something like what I have written below but in a smarter way. The code below is working fine but it's not a smart solution. Is there a possibility to write a loop, maybe an iterative loop

```
df2['dest_col'] = np.where(df2['month'] == 'March-2016',a
                  ,(np.where(df2['month'] == 'April-2016',b
                  ,(np.where(df2['month'] == 'May-2016',c)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want`numpy.select`:

```
cond=[(df2['month'] == month) for month in df2['month'].unique()]
values=[a, b, c] 

df2['dest_col'] = np.select(cond,values)
```

Comment: This will work but if I want to do this for 20 different months, then this will be very redundant. Is there a possibility to write a loop and assign values?

Comment: Yes you can use a for loop. See my updated solution!

Comment: Also depend on what month you want to use

Comment: I got this error :  list of cases must be same length as list of conditions               
 but when I can check back I have the same number of columns as compared to the number variables that I have created :

Comment: Yes, the list of length of values must be the same than the length of list of conditions. For each condition should there are a value.How to select the values depend on your aplication. Depend on what you want to do you should use numpy select

Comment: The length of values list is the output of `df2['month'].nunique()`

Comment: Correct.. Worked fine for me!